# How would you describe a stamp card?

Tags: vocabulario, adjetivos

How would you describe the concept of a stamp card to a customer? Like you get so many stamps or “points” and then a free drink when you fill it up?

Answer (score 4):

It's called [tarjeta de fidelización](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sxsrf=APwXEde_Refpm3ItQOejN9Gq8BFBsEng2w:1686188900478&q=tarjeta%20de%20fidelizacion&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFqb-Tx7L_AhUg_7sIHQQoCWEQ0pQJegQIDRAB&biw=360&bih=654&dpr=3) (loyalty card).

[image]

<sub>*Source [bartalentlab.com](https://www.bartalentlab.com/degustanews/gestion-hostelera/gestion-restaurantes/tarjeta-fidelizacion)*</sub>